# Catch multiple specific exception types in Dart with one catch expression

Tags: exception, dart, try-catch

I know I can catch a specific Exception type in dart with the following:

```
try {
  ...
} on SpecificException catch(e) {
  ...
}
```

But is there a way to catch multiple specific exception types with on line instead of using multiple catch statements?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to have something like python exception features.
`on (ExcType1, ExcType2) catch(e) {}`

Comment: It's not, And there is an open [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/112) on dart for this.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can only specify one type per `on xxx catch(e) {` line or alternatively use
`catch(e)` to catch all (remaining - see below) exception types.
The type after `on` is used as type for the parameter to `catch(e)`. Having a set of types for this parameter wouldn't work out well.

```
try {
  ...
} on A catch(e) {
  ...
} on B catch(e) {
  ...
} catch(e) { // everything else
}
```

Comment: Well, it would work at least as well as the generic "catch(e)" clause.  That is, if more than one type were specified in the `on` clause, the parameter to `catch()` could be `dynamic`.  (I get that it doesn't work that way, just saying it could have been done like that.)

Answer (score 31):

No, there isn't, but you can do this:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  if (e is A || e is B) {
    ...
  } else {
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps worth noting that exceptions of different type but with common ancestry can be caught by a single `on` statement. For example

```
abstract class A implements Exception {}

class B implements A {}

class C implements A {}

void main() {
  try {
    throw B();
  }
  on A {
    print('caught B using on A');
  }
  try {
    throw C();
  }
  on A {
    print('caught C using on A');
  }
}
```

which outputs

```
caught B using on A
caught C using on A
```