# Flutter : Dio HTTP Handling error exception 404

Tags: flutter, dart

## My Expect

[It's using Http.get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJqxD.gif)

I'm got problem with handling error Exception **DIO** package , I'm try in **HTTP** package it's work with this code:

```
 Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async{
       try {
         var apiRespon = await http.get('$baseURL/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
        if(apiRespon.statusCode == 200){
            final apiResponJson = json.decode(apiRespon.body);
            return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();
        }else{
          print(apiRespon.statusCode.toString());
            throw Exception('Failed Load Data with status code ${apiRespon.statusCode}');
        }
       }on Exception catch (e) {
         print(e);
         return null;
       }
  }
```

But if I change with **DIO** my app suddenly crash with error Exception even though I'm already handling this exception :

```
 Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async{
       try {
         var apiRespon = await dio.get('$baseURL/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
        if(apiRespon.statusCode == 200){
            final apiResponJson = apiRespon.data;
            return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();
        }else{
          print(apiRespon.statusCode.toString());
            throw Exception('Failed Load Data with status code ${apiRespon.statusCode}');
        }
       }on DioError catch (e) {
         print(e);
         return null;
       }
  }
```

My exception:

> error : null
> message :"Http status error [404]"
> Response ({"status":false,"message":"Data Not Found"})

I've already opened issue in github but not yet get solution.

Thanks

[This is my exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUU33.png)

Comment: Can you post the detail of the Exception that is raised ?

Comment: why did you removed `json.decode`? Also the iamge you posted (you should post text) is a 404 error, that means there is something wrong with the url, nothing was returned. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: @F-1 in **DIO** data already Map, and that's i remove ```json.decode``` ,  it's different if i'm using ```http.get```

Comment: @Muldec sorry, it's already in description on link image sir.

Comment: @F-1 on image, i'm already ScreenShot it on last question

Comment: What happens if you do this `if(apiRespon.statusCode < 200 || apiRespon.statusCode >= 300 || apiRespon.data == null){//fails}else{//do stuff}`

Comment: Sure it's on the image. But can you post it as a text for future reference and better indexing of your question ?

Comment: Also, why use `DioError catch (e)` instead of simply `catch(e)`, sorry I've never used this package

Comment: @F-1 why use ```DioError catch (e) ``` because it's **DIO** use in their github [Github](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio)

Comment: I had this problem and to solve that now I use `http` package instead of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch multiple specific exception types in Dart with one catch expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627717/catch-multiple-specific-exception-types-in-dart-with-one-catch-expression)

Comment: Is this a Jojo reference?

Answer (score 6):

In your first code, using the http package, if the status code is not 200, you raise an `Exception` that is catch by

```
on Exception catch (e) { ... }
```

However, in your second code with the DIO package, you raise the same `Exception` but it cannot be catched as you changed the catch condition

```
on DioError catch (e) { ... }
```

As the exception is not cathed by this, it is propagated through your app.

Comment: sorry, and what  the best solution for this ? 
i'm remove exception on ```if else ``` statement ?

Comment: I can't give you an answer to that question. It depends of how you want to manage your exceptions in you application and how you wnat to manage http status code.

Comment: on the point i want ignores the Exception error and make my app continue not crash, because i know it's surely ```404 not found ```

Comment: Then remode the line `throw Exception('Failed Load Data with status code ${apiRespon.statusCode}');`

Answer (score 3):

You can use .catchError() to catch exception when `statusCode <> 200`

```
Future<void> _postRequest() async {
    ...
    await RequestUtil().post(path, data: data)
        .then(_handleDioResponse)
        .catchError(_handleDioError);
}

void _handleDioResponse(dynamic response){
    ...
}

void _handleDioError(dynamic error){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.catchError()` catch exception:

```
dio.post().then(){ }.catchError(){ }
```

and `try catch` is invalid.
see more: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/398